# Is every finite subgroup of multiplicative subgroup of an integral domain cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Here is a well-known theorem:

> Let $F$ be a field and $G$ be a finite subgroup of $F^*$. Then, $G$ is cyclic.

Can this theorem be extended to integral domain?

Here's a lemma in Weil's elementary number theory:

> Let $G$ be a finite group such that [$\forall d\in\mathbb{Z}^+, d||G|\Rightarrow |\{x\in G: x^d=e\}|≦d$].
>
> Then, $G$ is cyclic.

Now, let $R$ be an integral domain and $G$ be a finite subgroup of $R^*$.

Since $R$ is an integral domain, for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, $ |\{\alpha\in R: \alpha^n = 1\}|≦deg(X^n -1) = n$.

Hence, by the above lemma, $G$ is cyclic.

Is my argument correct?

Comment: Why is it downvoted?

Comment: Yeah, its correct. I was just now wondering why they dont usually state it like that.

Comment: I have always wondered why it is not stated that way, because being a field plays no role at all in the proof (except maybe that more people are comfortable with polynomials over fields than over integeral domains...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The units of an integral domain build a subgroup of the units of its quotient field.

Comment: I see now why my post was downvoted..

Comment: Quotient field is not to be confused with a quotient ring that happens to be a field. That is why I think "field of fractions" is a slightly better name.